# Trouble porting a Chrome extension to Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to port a chrome extension to firefox.

In chrome I had been accessing a certain image using :

```
chrome.extension.getURL('img/full_logo.png')
```

In firefox I tried to achieve the same with the following :

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
self.data.url('img/full_logo.png');
```

But the firefox console gives error saying require is not defined which i understand is not a javascript function.

What is this require function?
How can I get the URL of the image for my firefox add-on?
Any valuable links are also be appreciated.

Comment: This code should go in main.js and you are doing this from the addon-sdk right? You have to download and set that up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation

Comment: @Noitidart : Yes, I am doing this from the add-on sdk. The variables that I declare in main.js are for reasons I cant understand undefined in other js files. Basically I want to use images in the data/img folder in my extension.

Comment: The code above works correctly in backend scripts (like main.js), but won't work in content scripts. What js file are you trying to access the image from?

Comment: @willlma I am trying to access it from a content script.

Comment: Then you'll have to send it to a content script using `port.emit`. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port)

Answer (score 2):

Why access the image from addon code if you know it's name? When you can directly link to it from your content markup.

Consider this directory structure:

```
├── data
│   ├── html
│   │   └── ui.html
│   ├── images
│   │   └── image.png
│   └── js
│       └── contentScript.js
```

Inside `ui.html` use below to use the image ..

```
<img src="../images/image.png"></img>
```